# Clicking first link/ patent after search in Google Patents using Selenium in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to click on the first result from the Google patents search page using selenium in python with chromedriver.

It automatically types the company from a list in the search bar and enters.

```
        driver.get("https://patents.google.com/")

        searchbar = driver.find_element_by_id("searchInput")
        searchbar.send_keys(Company[i], Keys.ENTER)
```

This is what I used after in order to find the first link and execute the click.

```
        time.sleep(20)
        element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='link']")
        element[0].click()
```

However, it does not identify the element for some reason and won't click the link.

This is the HTML:

```
  <article class="result style-scope search-result-item">
    <state-modifier class="result-title style-scope search-result-item" act="{&quot;type&quot;: &quot;OPEN_RESULT&quot;, &quot;result&quot;: &quot;$result&quot;}" data-result="patent/US3334718A/en"><a id="link" href="/patent/US3334718A/en?assignee=AAR+CORP&amp;oq=AAR+CORP" class="style-scope state-modifier">
      <h3 class="style-scope search-result-item"><raw-html class="style-scope search-result-item">
<span id="htmlContent" class="style-scope raw-html" style="display: inline;"> Cargo handling appartus</span>
```

I hope it makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you've forgot to invoke `click` method.
Try to alter your code a little

```
time.sleep(20)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='link']")
element[0].click()  # <- add parentheses to invoke the method
```

This is caused, since the functions are objects just like any other object in Python.
If you forget to add parentheses, you are referring to the function object, not the function itself.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I already fixed it but it still won't work. It will execute the time.sleep() but then just goes to the next company without opening the first result.

Comment: Could you please provide more code, since it's strange that the code above is not executed.
Also you can go for another approach that would work in the same way:
Obtain elements' hrefs instead of elements themselves and you could iterate over the hrefs list and `get` each of them:

`element_hrefs = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//search-result-item/*//@href")` and then 
`for element in element_hrefs:
    driver.get(element)
    sleep(10)
`

Comment: I assumed that it has something to do with the HTML, that the link is hidden in some frame, which is the reason why it cannot be called. Obtaining elements' hrefs did not work either. Here is more of the code: 

`def openURL(threadID, threadName, URL, counter):
    
    while counter:
        if exitFlag:
            threadName.exit()
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOptions)
        Citing_Content = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=["Company", "Id", "Citing"])            
        for i in range (0, 2500):
            i = i*10+threadID
            start = time.time()`

Comment: Could you please try to obtain the hrefs with the following xpath selector and to try again?

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a/@href[contains(.,'patentimages')]")`

Comment: It will stop right there and proceed with the next company after checking the driver connection with: 
`driver_connection = 0
            'check if webdriver is still running; only continue if functionality is given'
            while driver_connection <1:
                try:
                    driver.get('file:///C:/')
                    driver_connection = 1
                except:
                    driver_connection = 0
                    time.sleep(3)
                    print('driver crashed')
                    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
                    continue`